# force:closeQuickAction not working on doinit

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to close quick action after `e.force:editRecord` event, I tried without `e.force:editRecord` event but in that case also quick action is not closing, I tried with `setInterval` function with delay 1s, this also not works for me. Any advice

```
({
  doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    if ($A.get("$Browser.isPhone")) {
      component.set("v.isMobileorTablet", true);
    } else if ($A.get("$Browser.isTablet")) {
      component.set("v.isMobileorTablet", true);
    } else {
      var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
      editRecordEvent.setParams({
        recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
      });

      editRecordEvent.fire();
      $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: are you sure that your code doesn't fail before the `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();` line?

Comment: code is running fine

Comment: which quick action are you trying to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doinit is for initialization where the dom and listeners are not ready

```
({
  doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    if ($A.get("$Browser.isPhone")) {
      component.set("v.isMobileorTablet", true);
    } else if ($A.get("$Browser.isTablet")) {
      component.set("v.isMobileorTablet", true);
    } else {
      var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
      editRecordEvent.setParams({
        recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
      });
      var action = component.get('c.closeAction');
       //or
       //var action = component.get('c.anotherOption'); 
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
      editRecordEvent.fire();

    }
  },
 closeAction :function(component, event, helper){
    $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
 },
 anotherOption : function(){
   setTimeout(()=>{
       let quickActionClose = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
       quickActionClose.fire();
    },1000);
 }
});
```

Comment: Ahh! option 1 works for me thanks!

Comment: I am calling multiple helper methods in doInit(which are having server apex calls) and again in helper methods i am making server apex calls so where should my closequickaction be placed, please help me tried many things even this approach but nothing is working out.

Comment: Please log another question whiteout seeing code it is not possible to answer. You should not do multiple server call from doinit use wrapper to get the data at once.